# c++ template specialization - linker error multiple definitions

Tags: c++, template-specialization

My third question here today ;-), but I am really new to c++ template programming and operator overloading.

I am trying the following:

terminallog.hh

```
//snipped code

class Terminallog {
public:

    Terminallog();
    Terminallog(int);
    virtual ~Terminallog();

    template <class T>
    Terminallog & operator<<(const T &v);
    template <class T>
    Terminallog & operator<<(const std::vector<T> &v);
    template <class T>
    Terminallog & operator<<(const T v[]);
    Terminallog & operator<<(const char v[]);

//snipped code
};

//snipped code
template <class T>
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const T &v) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    this->indent();
    std::cout << v;
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const std::vector<T> &v) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        this->indent();
        std::cout << "Element " << i << ": " << v.at(i);
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const T v[]) {
    unsigned int elements = sizeof (v) / sizeof (v[0]);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
        std::cout << std::endl;
        this->indent();
        std::cout << "Element " << i << ": " << v[i];
    }
    return *this;
}

Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const char v[]) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    this->indent();
    std::cout << v;
    return *this;
}
//snipped code
```

Trying to compile this code, it gives me a linker error:

```
g++ src/terminallog.cc inc/terminallog.hh testmain.cpp -o test -Wall -Werror 
/tmp/ccifyOpr.o: In function `Terminallog::operator<<(char const*)':
testmain.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Terminallog::operator<<(char const*)'
/tmp/cccnEZlA.o:terminallog.cc:(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Therfore I am currently banging my head against the wall, searching for a solution. But I can't find one in the wall...

It would be great if someone could show me my mistake

Thank you so much

ftiaronsem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This function

```
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const char v[]) {
    std::cout << std::endl;
    this->indent();
    std::cout << v;
    return *this;
}
```

is not a template, but a regular member function. If this .h file is included in several .cpp filtes, it will cause the multiple definition error you're seeing. If you declare it `inline`, the compiler will allow the multiple definitions and your error should be fixed.

```
inline
Terminallog &Terminallog::operator<<(const char v[]) {
```

Comment: wow, perfectly correct. Thank you so much. But I still have one question: I have an include guard in that header file. Therefore it should only be included once. Why am I getting this error nevertheless?

Comment: @fitaronsem: Include guards help with multiple definitions _only_ within a single TU. Your error is a _link_ error, not a compile error; include guards don't help when you have multiple definitions across multiple TUs. Therefore, as a general rule, don't put non-inline or non-template function or variable definitions in a header.

Comment: Include guards prevent it from being included multiple times in the process of compiling a *single* .cpp file, thus prevent the *compiler error* of defining the class multiple times. However, the problem you're seeing is not a compiler error, but a *linker error*. That is, when your multiple .cpp files are joined to make the final executable or library file. Thus you need to tell the linker that it's ok to accept multiple *identical* copies of this function, and `inline` serves that purpose.

Comment: @fitaronsem: Here's a [slightly confusing article](http://kera.name/articles/2009/03/tomalaks-tuesday-tip-4-conventional-thinking/) that may help you nonetheless.

Comment: @Pablo: The extension of a file has very little to do with it. It's about translation units, which may not be restricted to one ".cpp file".

Comment: @Pablo: .. and `inline` is unnecessary for function templates. They are not "automatically inlined", but many of the same rules apply due to the way in which they are instantiated.

Comment: @Tomalak agree on both points, I just wanted to keep the explanation simple :) I should've followed the explanation with further reading material, I guess.

Comment: @Pablo, @Tomalak: Thank you both for the excellent comments and both were equally useful. I have no knowledge of translation units and similar compiler stuff. Therefore pablos comment served me definitly well. However the link to that article was also great. It gave me an insight why I am getting some errors. Thank you both for these comments. P.S.: I will try a search on the web to find out what a compilation unit might be, but that is for tomorrow, I am going to sleep right now ;-).

Comment: @fiaronsem: a compilation unit is what the compiler see, after the preprocessor did its job. Roughly speaking, it's your source file (generally `.c` or `.cpp`) with all the headers that you included bluntly copied and pasted and all the macros expanded.

Comment: @ftiaronsem: That you don't know about Translation Units means you don't know that Pablo's response wasn't strictly correct, which is a problem. :) That's why I stepped in to make sure you get the real facts.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971837/linux-c-how-to-properly-use-template-specializations-across-multiple-files