# Linux C++: How to properly use template specializations across multiple files?

Tags: c++, linux, templates, linker

I have a strange problem. On Windows, with Visual Studio 2010 and also with the Intel Compiler everything is linked as expected. But when I try to compile my code with CLang 3.0 on Linux, it does compile (and if I only use a single CPP file it does also link and run) but does not link.

The message is that there are multiple symbol definitions, referring to template instanciations. For example consider the following two lines in a header file shared across multiple compilation units:

```
 template<class T> void myFunc(T in) { }
 template<> void myFunc<int>(int in) { }
```

Now from the Linux linker I would get something along the lines of:

> "file xyz": Multiple definition of "myFunc(int in)", first defined in "some file".

But how would I prevent that? Since it works on Windows I suppose it should work on Linux too somehow?

The same goes for static template data members, which are more or less the same as above just that you declare a variable instead of a function. I would prefer if it worked for static template data members.

If everything else fails I suppose I could still create a "MakeAll.cpp" file which just includes all CPP there are, but that doesn't sound like a desirable solution to me...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you using #include guards?

Comment: @SteveC the user is stating that the code compiles but does not link. The include guards would trigger compiler errors rather than link time errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my understanding, you are in fact defining your template specializations multiple times, and this should also give you an error for Windows compilers.

In your header file you are *defining* a function by providing a body:

```
template<> void myFunc<int>(int in) { }
```

This definition will exist in multiple compilation units and the linker *should* complain.

The same rules apply for your template specialization as for ordinary non-template functions: Either use `inline` or use a separate declaration and definition, by putting

```
template<> void myFunc<int>(int in);
```

in a header and

```
template<> void myFunc<int>(int in)
{
    // ...
}
```

in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: It does not complain on Windows. I will try the inlining thing as soon as possible ;). The point is that I need static template data members (that is my current approach). And they come with the very same issue just that I can't inline them?!

Comment: This answer is incomplete. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5453361/c-template-specialization-linker-error-multiple-definitions

Answer (score 3):

Templates are instantiated by the compiler, and it is the compilers responsibility to make sure that they are only defined once.

When you fully specialize a function, it is not a template anymore (but an ordinary function), and it is *your* responsibility to make sure it is not multiply defined.

There is very little difference between these functions

```
template<>
void f<int>(int x)
{ }

void f(int x)
{ }
```

when it comes to the one definition rule.

Adding `inline` helps in both cases.

Comment: Ok maybe it is a bug in CLang 3 then. Maybe you also have a solution for static template data members?! They cause the same trouble and I can't inline them...

Comment: I think Clang is correct, but it is not really an error for others to make it work anyway. :-) And I don't think there is a solution for the data members, other than splitting your macros in two parts, one for the header and one for the implementation.

Comment: of the top dozen google entries on "multiple definition template specialization" your answer was the only one explaining why!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the standard at hand now, but I think that the specialization has to be declared `inline`.

Comment: I will try that but what would I do about static template datamembers?! They produce the same error but I can't inline them...

Comment: @thesaint you will have to move the definitions of static data members of *full speceializations* (I.e. independent of any template argument) to a single translation unit. The thing is that a full specialization is not a template, and not being a template it does not play by template rules.

Comment: The point is that this is not possible! Because they have to be declared in shared headers. Usually, you can simply prepend a "static" in front of data declaration to make them private to each compilation unit, but this doesn't work for template data?! And this is probably the reason why the MSVC linker ignores these conflicts. Because if I have no way to get rid of them in code, the Linker just does a silly job if it reports an error instead of a warning; at least if there is nothing I can do about it?!

Comment: PS: The reason I can't move them into one single compilation unit is, that they arrive via macro expansion. And to expand it, I need the parameters. And creating two macros with the same (large set of) parameters is not what I am going to do. So I need to find another way...

Comment: @thesaint I think we are talking about two different uses of static here. Do you mean static as *internal to the translation unit*, or static as *class level member*? Those are completely different uses of the keyword, and unless we are on the same page we are not going to make any sense of the discussion

Comment: Okay, you mean this will work for compilation unit static template members?! I will try that, since it would probably be possible in my case... Just a little naming issue then, but I think its solvable.